# How to Merge Gridview Row with same value in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview column below

```
row1  |  row1  |  row1  | row1
row2  |  row2  |  row2  | row2
Total |  Total |  Total | Total2
row4  |  row4  |  row4  | row4
row5  |  row5  |  row5  | row5
row6  |  row6  |  row6  | row6
row7  |  row7  |  row7  | row7
Total |  Total |  Total | Total4
```

and i want merge gridview rows, below is the output:

```
row1  |  row1  |  row1  | row1
row2  |  row2  |  row2  | row2
                  Total | Total2
row4  |  row4  |  row4  | row4
row5  |  row5  |  row5  | row5
row6  |  row6  |  row6  | row6
row7  |  row7  |  row7  | row7
                  Total | Total4
```

how can to merge gridview rows like above, i want to give color every Total row

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the gridview RowDataBound event.

At first setup the GV with the appropriate controls then populate the GV with your data and assign the controls with values from your object.

Start with http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource17-RowDatabound-event-tips-and-tricks-in-Gridview-control.aspx.aspx

and

http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/120/Aspnet-GridView-RowDataBound-example-using-C-.aspx

to get you heading towards the right direction